# Google Maps API v3 & fusion layers: polygon opacity

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to import a Fusion Layer of polygons into a google map via api v3. The map and the fusion layer is coming through fine but the fillOpacity and fillColour are not taking effect after saving the fusion table or by the maps api:

```
    var fusionTableId = "1Rd2LBEusHQsjsMAVsgYm_E_4OlpqgSb07ojJRL3O";
    fusionLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(fusionTableId,{
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
        map: map,
        styles: [{
            polygonOptions: {
                fillColor: "#00FF00",
                fillOpacity: 0.3
            }
        }]
    });
    fusionLayer.setMap(map);
```

The polygon is coming through in a default red colour and there seems to be no combination of changes I can make to change the colour.

Ideally I just want the opacity turned down to 1% but I've tried changing the colour (as above) with no joy.

Any hints/tips?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the "old" FusionTablesLayer syntax `FusionTablesLayer(FusionTableId, options:FusionTablesLayerOptions)`

```
var fusionTableId = "1Rd2LBEusHQsjsMAVsgYm_E_4OlpqgSb07ojJRL3O";
fusionLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(fusionTableId,{
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    map: map,
    styles: [{
        polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: "#00FF00",
            fillOpacity: 0.3
        }
    }]
});
fusionLayer.setMap(map);
```

The [current syntax](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesLayer) is:
 `FusionTablesLayer(options:FusionTablesLayerOptions)` (which supports the dynamic styling you are attempting to use) would be:

```
var fusionTableId = "1Rd2LBEusHQsjsMAVsgYm_E_4OlpqgSb07ojJRL3O";
fusionLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    map: map,
    query: {
      from: fusionTableId,
      select: "geometry"
    },
    styles: [{
        polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: "#00FF00",
            fillOpacity: 0.3
        }
    }]
});
fusionLayer.setMap(map);
```

(as you discovered)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the answer was staring me in the face - code changed slightly to this and it worked a charm:

```
    var fusionTableId = "1Rd2LBEusHQsjsMAVsgYm_E_4OlpqgSb07ojJRL3O";
    fusionLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        map: map,
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
        query: {
          select: "geometry",
          from: fusionTableId
        },
        styles: [{
            polygonOptions: {
                fillColor: "#00FF00",
                fillOpacity: 0.3
            }
        }]
    });
```